# SQL Selecting Values Based on Hierarchically-Ordered List

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table (at the bottom) with base values `A1, A2, A3, A4 ... An`, and overriding values `B1, B3`, and `C2, C3, C4` and `D1, D4`.

The data could be visualized like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4
B1      B3 
C1  C2      C4
    D2  D3
```

With SQLite and the table below, if I have an ordered list of Letters A, B, C, and D in any order and length, I'd want the table to return those values contained in the highest level, and then fill in the missing holes from the lower levels.

Example: `[D > B > A]` (omitting C) should grab all the values 1-4 from "D": `[D2, D3]`, then get missing values for 1 and 4 from B `[B1]` and finally the missin 4 from A `[A4]` to yield `[B1, D2, D3, A4]`. but `[C > B > A]` would return `[C1, C2, B3, C4]`. The order of the returne

```
Input          Output
C > B > A      [C1, C2, B3, C4]
B > A          [B1, A2, B3, A4]
A > B > C > D  [A1, A2, A3, A4]
D > C > A      [C1, D2, D3, C4]
B > D          [B1, D2, D3] or [B1, D2, D3, null]
B              [B1, B3] or [B1, null, N3, null]
```

So in my table I have my data arranged like this. In this table `Number + Letter` is a composite key. Any combination of these rows will return either zero or one row. The rows are not guaranteed to be in any particular order: the example table is for ease of explanation. The results do not need to be in any certain order.

| ID (PK) | Number | Letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | *a* |
| 2 | 2 | A | *b* |
| 3 | 3 | A | *c* |
| 4 | 4 | A | *d* |
| 5 | 1 | B | *e* |
| 6 | 3 | B | *f* |
| 7 | 1 | C | *g* |
| 8 | 2 | C | *h* |
| 9 | 4 | C | *i* |
| 10 | 2 | D | *j* |
| 11 | 3 | D | *k* |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number`. `Params` CTE specifies the input hierarchy, C > B > A for example

```
with params(Letter, Pos) as (
  select 'A', 3 union all
  select 'B', 2 union all
  select 'C', 1 union all
  select 'D', -1 
)
select *
from(
 select t.*, row_number() over(partition by c.Number order by p.Pos) rn
 from mytable c
 join params p on p.Letter = c.Letter
   and p.Pos > 0
)t 
where rn = 1;
```

Returns

```
ID  Number  Letter  Value   rn
7   1   C   g   1
8   2   C   h   1
6   3   B   f   1
9   4   C   i   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `exists` with a subquery:

```
with inp(letter) as ( 
  select "D"
  union all
  select "B"
  union all
  select "A"
),
cte as (
  select row_number() over (order by 1) r, t1.number, t1.letter 
  from inp t join test t1 on t.letter = t1.letter
)
select c.number, c.letter from cte c where not exists (select 1 from cte c1 where c1.r < c.r and c.number = c1.number)
order by c.number
```